# Get None after connection to Postgres via SSH Tunnel using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh, psycopg2, ssh-tunnel

I use following code for connection to Postgres DB:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_password=ssh_password, 
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, 5432)
        ) as server:
        
        server.start()
        print("server connected")

        params = {
            'host': 'localhost',
            'port': server.local_bind_port,
            'user': sql_username,
            'password': sql_password,
            'database': sql_database
            }

        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        conn = conn.cursor()

        curs = conn.execute("SELECT VERSION();")
        print(curs)

        result = curs.fetchall()
        print(result)

        # Close connections
        conn.close()
        print("database connected")
```

In 'curs' I get 'None' but DB is not empty (I use pgAdmin for checking). What could be a problem? Where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all very misleading.  You overwrite your "conn" variable with a cursor (rendering the connection inaccessible directly anymore), then save the results of the execute in something misleadingly named "curs".  Of course "curs" is None after this, that is what execute() is documented to return.

But then your fetchall returns an error (which you don't show), because you are calling it on the wrong thing, that is, a None which has been stored into a variable misleadingly named "curs".

There is no point in saving the results of the execute call itself, as either it throws an error and so returns nothing, or it succeeds and returns None.

The block should look something like this:

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    curs = conn.cursor()

    curs.execute("SELECT VERSION();")
    print(curs)  # no point in doing this really

    result = curs.fetchall()
    print(result)
```